# How can I use an hstore column type with Npgsql?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, hstore

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
  id serial primary key,
  login varchar(40) not null,
  password varchar(40) not null,
  data hstore
);
```

I'd like to use an `NpgsqlCommand` object with parameters to retrieve and store the account data from my application. Which DbType do I have to use for the `NpgsqlParameter`? The enum `NpgsqlDbType` does not have a value for hstore. Can I use a `Dictionary` or `HashTable` as value of the `NpgsqlParameter` object?

When I use a JSON column I can create a parameter of type `NpgsqlDbType.Text`, use a library like JSON.Net to serialize an object to a JSON string and send an SQL statement like that:

```
INSERT INTO account (login, password, data) VALUES (:login, :password, :data::json)
```

Unfortunately this does not work with an hstore column. I get a syntax error when I try to do this:

```
INSERT INTO account (login, password, data) VALUES (:login, :password, :data::hstore)
```

The string I pass to the data parameter looks like this:

> 'key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2"'

Comment: What is the error you get? Although there is no hstore native data type in Npgsql, if you can handle your hstore data as a string, you can try DbType.Object and/or NpgsqlDbType.Text. Also, enable Postgresql Server log, or print the NpgsqlException.ErrorSql property so we can see which query Npgsql is sending to server. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, Francisco! I saw in the log that the single quotes (') at the beginning and the end of the string are escaped when they are passed to PostgreSQL. When I pass

> key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2"

instead, I can insert the data into the hstore column.